# Wso2 identity server 5.1 no identity service issue when power loss to one server in cluster

Tags: wso2, hazelcast, wso2-identity-server

We have two `wso2` identity servers deployed. I will refer to them as `EIS` and `EIS 2`. 
The version of the identity server is `5.1.0`.
The membership scheme we are using is `wka`.

My problem can be reproduced in the following steps:

1) Both servers are up and running.

2) Abruptly take down `EIS 1.` - simulated power switch off, no shut down of service.

3) `EIS 2` continues to think `EIS 1` is still there (it still holds a connection to it on port `4000`) but any attempt to authenticate to the portal fails for about `10` minutes. After `10` minutes `EIS 2` recognizes that `EIS 1` server is no longer there.

4) `EIS` service comes back after `10` minutes.

I am wondering if there are connection settings to tell the identity server (`EIS 2`) to recognize earlier that it is not getting a response from `EIS 1` so it can release the connection and continue to provide `EIS` service with one server?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of a delay in network or you are having a higher heartbeat value in hazelcast. You can configure the hazelcast properties in any wso2 products.

Basically you can add a hazelcast.properties file to `<CARBON_HOME>/repository/conf/` directory and add relevant properties there.

Follow the details on https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Additional+Configurations+and+Information